# Can I respawn a locked Royal Sorcerer Navlaan?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Can I respawn him if I use an ascetic on the Aldia's keep bonfire ?

If not is there a way to respawn him trapped (other than NG+). I didn't talk to him before freeing him and I want his quests and armor set.

(I would have tried already but I don't want to give HP to the monsters there, they already have plenty ...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, he doesn't reset until you start a new game.